# Is there a way to fix Oracle query in shared pool

Tags: performance, oracle, sql-execution-plan

I have a report engine, performing PreparedStatements on Oracle 11, that is a highly prioritized task.

What I see is that first query invocation usually performs much much longer than the same query afterwards (query has different parameters and return different data).

I suppose this is due to hard parsing done by Oracle, on first query invocation.

I wonder, is there a way of hinting to Oracle, that this query is highly prioritized query which would be performed often, and which performance is critical, so it should remain in shared pool, no matter what?

I know that I can fix execution plan in Oracle 11, but I don't want to fix it, I want Oracle still to be able to change it, as system changes, all I want is to exclude query hard parsing.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you should change your "I suppose..." into a "I tested and have determined..." :)

The query performance may be affected by more than just parsing; when it executes it has to fetch blocks from disk into the buffer cache - subsequent executions quite possibly are taking advantage of the blocks being found in memory and so are faster.

EDIT: to answer your immediate question - a workaround may be to have a job run periodically that parses the query but doesn't execute it. You might even be able to use this to determine whether parsing or fetching is the locus of the problem.

Comment: I can't say that I tested because I do not have DBA access on the DB, and can't see any Oracle technical tables, So I can only assume things there. I can't even use AUTOTRACE. I also had a guess about cache, that is why I tested with different parameters, parameters for prior dates e t.c., that should not have been extracted to the cache, to exclude cache influence, but still no effect.

Comment: If you don't test, or find someone who can, you'd have to resort to the "shotgun" approach - just try all sorts of random changes until it seems to improve.

Comment: There is even a tool for that kind of approach Quest SQL Optimizer 8.0.0 for Oracle. This was my first resort:)

Answer (score 1):

Anton,
if your query is using bind variables it will be re-used. The cursor will be cached and as long as it is re-used, it will remain in the cursor cache. Make sure that it uses bind variables. This increases re-usability and scalability.

If you don't trust the rdbms you can pin it using dbms_shared_pool.keep. 
See http://psoug.org/reference/dbms_shared_pool.html

You need to find your cursor in order to do so.
Normally there is an other problem that should be fixed.

Ronald.
http://ronr.blogspot.com

Comment: It does use bind variables. But will it be kept if cache is overloaded. The problem, as I see it, is that cache remove this query durring the day, and hard parse it again afterwards.

Comment: In that case, the shared_pool is too small or other parts of the app fire too much unshareable sql. Normally the rdbms will try to re-use and cache everything it can and not remove something it recognizes as valuable.

Comment: Yes, that is the original question. I wonder, can I hint Oracle not to remove this query from shared_pool. In other words, set it as most "valuable" query in share pool, regarding usability, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can try pinning to shared pool using [dbms_shared_pool.keep](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_shared_pool.htm#i999221)

But I would first make sure that you have an aging out problem first

Comment: Thanks, it seems interesting. 
According to specification, _I need to make a function for it, to put it in a pool this way, wright?_, or simple query would also work? And what kind of function should it be?

Comment: _A cursor can be kept by DBMS_SHARED_POOL.KEEP('0034CDFF, 20348871'). The complete hexadecimal address must be in the first 8 characters_ Is this the way?

Comment: I would put in a function/procedure if you're going to use pinning